# OpenCV can't use VideoCapture with url

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, opencv, python

I'm trying to open a video from a Google Cloud Storage url and process it in a cloud function - the file is publicly available. But `v.read()` returns `None`.

Sample video url: https://storage.googleapis.com/dev-brdu1976/268.mov

```
v = cv2.VideoCapture(request.json['Source_Storage_Path'])
    print(v)
    frameNum = -1
    while (True):
        ret_value,frame = v.read()
        if ret_value == False or frame is None:
            print('Frame is None')
            break
        frameNum += 1
        #do stuff
```

Comment: it is always recommended to do v.isOpened() after it is created, to check if at least manage to open the file. It also could be that it can't open such file (maybe codec is missing?), have you tried another file with another codec? You may try with another backend as well, i.e. FFMPeg instead of GStreamer or vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to make it work but I didn't dig into the specifics. Requesting the video via https doesn't open - it did work when I changed the url protocol to http instead.